# Calendar React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a homework to make a calendar component on React
It has to show days like Windows calendar, start from Sunday even if it's an other month and ends with Saturday
[image: like on screen]

And HTML has to be made like table (tr (weeks)...td (days)...)
it has to be:

one week:

```
    <tr>
    <td>day1</td>
    <td>day2</td>
    <td>day3</td>
    <td>day4</td>
    <td>day5</td>
    <td>day6</td>
    <td>day7</td>
    </tr>
```

- then next week the same

I have prepared an array with dates, array starts from Sunday and ends with Saturday
I was trying map() it and put jsx tags with dates inside. That works
But when I'm trying to put inside week tags (tr) I can't do it because I'm trying to put inside

```
</tr><tr>
```

- closing one week and opening next week (I can't add one closing jsx tag)

I'm stuck

Could you give me some advises?

Comment: what do you mean "closing one week and opening next week"?

Comment: I mean that </tr> is tag that I have to put at the end of each week and <tr> I have to put at the beginning of each week. So each week starts with <tr> and ends with </tr>, each day starts with <td> and ends with </td>. So each row is a week and each cell is a day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you an example for your reference:

```
import React from 'react';
export default function Calendar() {
  let dateNum = 1;
  let firstDay = new Date('2023-02-10'),
    firstWeekDay;
  let i;
  let lastDate;
  let month = [];
  let week = [];
  firstDay.setDate(1);
  lastDate = new Date(firstDay.getTime());
  lastDate.setMonth(lastDate.getMonth() + 1); // the first day of the next month
  lastDate = new Date(lastDate.getTime() - 86400000); //the first day of the next month minus 1 day
  firstWeekDay = firstDay.getDay();

  for (i = 0; i < firstWeekDay; i++) {
    week.push('');
  }
  for (i = firstWeekDay; i < 7; i++) {
    week.push(dateNum++);
  }
  month.push(week);
  console.log(dateNum <= lastDate.getDate());
  
  while (dateNum <= lastDate.getDate()){
    week=[];
    for (i=0; i <7 ;i++){
      if (dateNum <= lastDate.getDate()) {
        week.push(dateNum++);
      } else {
        week.push("");
      }
    }
    month.push(week);
  }
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Sun</td>
          <td>Mon</td>
          <td>Tue</td>
          <td>Wed</td>
          <td>Thu</td>
          <td>Fri</td>
          <td>Sat</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      {month.map((week) => (
        <tr>
          {week.map((day) => (
            <td>{day}</td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  );
}
```